# pushState in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to get pushState to work in my backbone app. It works fine when just clicking the link. But if i refresh a page i get 404.

Router

```
Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'home': 'home'

    },

    home: function() {
        new HomeView({el:'#main-view'})
    }
});
```

When a-tag gets clicked:

```
event.preventDefault();
App.navigate(event.target.pathname, { trigger: true });
```

start history:

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState:true});
```

and html:

```
                <li>
                    <a href="/home">home</a>
                </li>
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: sure, can bet you dont have any page available by this URL

Comment: Its a single page app. And in backbone you can't really load pages (as fas as i know) in a good way. Every view loads its own template. (underscore.js).

Comment: From http://backbonejs.org/#History - "Note that using real URLs requires your web server to be able to correctly render those pages, so back-end changes are required as well." Also this may help you to understand https://blog.twitter.com/2012/implementing-pushstate-for-twittercom

Comment: @Evgeniy right. If you getting 404 for that page, it means your server can't find the route.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you use **a real HTML link**, so it **refreshes the page**, it's the normal behaviour.
But you would like to change only the current route, not to reload the page.

For that, you can handle the links to say to Backbone : "handle my links !".

Here is an example of the JS that I use to handle links that have "innerlink" CSS class as a route.

```
'use strict';
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var $ = require('jquery');
Backbone.$ = $;

module.exports = function() {
  // Use absolute URLs  to navigate to anything not in your Router.

  var openLinkInTab = false;

  // Only need this for pushState enabled browsers
  if (Backbone.history._hasPushState) {


    // console.log('YES you have push state !');

    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
      if (event.ctrlKey || event.keyCode === 91) {
        openLinkInTab = true;
      }
    });

    $(document).keyup(function() {
      openLinkInTab = false;
    });

    // Use delegation to avoid initial DOM selection and allow all matching elements to bubble
    $(document).on('click', 'a.innerlink', function(evt) {
      // Get the anchor href and protcol
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      var protocol = this.protocol + '//';

      console.log('backbone_pushstate_router:', href, protocol);

      evt.preventDefault();

      // Ensure the protocol is not part of URL, meaning its relative.
      // Stop the event bubbling to ensure the link will not cause a page refresh.
      if (!openLinkInTab && href.slice(protocol.length) !== protocol) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        // Note by using Backbone.history.navigate, router events will not be
        // triggered.  If this is a problem, change this to navigate on your
        // router.
        Backbone.history.navigate(href, true);
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.warn('no push state');
  }
};
```

Enjoy :)